# Subordination principle proof

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

I have trouble proving the Subordination principle for the Harnack distance.

If $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open, the Hanack distance $\tau_G(z,w)$ is defined as the smallest number such that $$h(w)\tau_G(z,w)^{-1}\leq h(z)\leq \tau_G(z,w)h(w)$$ for every positive harmonic function $h$ on $G$.

Now the subordination principle states:
Let $f:G_1\to G_2$ be a holomorphic mapping between two domains. Then $\tau_{G_{2}}(f(z),f(w))\leq \tau_{G_{1}}(z,w)$ with equality if $f$ is conformal.

It's true that $$h(f(w))\tau_{G_{1}}(z,w)^{-1}\leq h(f(z))\leq \tau_{G_{1}}(z,w)h(f(w))$$ but I can't seem to figure out to show the last part.

Also, why does equality hold if $f$ is conform?

Comment: If $f$ is conformal, then by the first part applied to $f^{-1}$ we have $\tau_{G_1}(f^{-1}(u), f^{-1}(v)) \leqslant \tau_{G_2}(u,v)$. Write $u = f(z),\, v = f(w)$ and you're done. Note that "conformal" must mean biholomorphic here. For a non-injective locally conformal mapping the inequality is strict for $z\neq w$ with $f(z) = f(w)$ at least if $G_1$ is a nice domain.